# Etiquette of wearing the wrong academic robes at graduation as a lecturer in the UK

Tags: etiquette, united-kingdom, graduation, outward-appearance, academic-dress

I have graduated three times from UK universities. First was a bachelors' degree, then a Masters' degree, then a PhD. The graduation robes associated with my PhD graduation are absolutely horrible. I am now a lecturer in a UK university and if I attend graduation ceremonies at this University (or others, I suppose), I am supposed to wear the academic robes from my highest degree, i.e. the horrible PhD ones.

So my question is this, is it considered acceptable to wear the robes from my 'lower' degrees at such occasions, or even the equivalent PhD robes from the university I now work at (much nicer!)?

Basically, can I get away with wearing the wrong robes to graduation ceremonies?

Comment: I am struggling to imagine what negative consequences you could really face for wearing the "wrong" robes.

Comment: a kilt is probably not acceptable.

Comment: Wouldn't that question be more suitable for a site on medieval role-playing?

Comment: It probably depends on the university. I would expect Oxbridge to care more. But it is also the case at Oxford and Cambridge that you shouldn't wear academic dress from another institution. So it may be acceptable for you to wear the equivalent robes of your current university.

Comment: I'm curious, what university? I personally love the "horrible" robes I see at graduations.

Comment: There are usually regulations on what you should wear which will be online. You can make your own decision about whether you want to break them of course.

Comment: A kilt is totally acceptable!

Comment: And my PhD (in engineering) comes from Heriot-Watt University. The robes in question are plain cerise-pink, with a cerise-pink hood!  http://oic.eps.hw.ac.uk/fun/photos/Graduation2002/Grad2002_3.jpg

Comment: @DrC those robes are are awesome. wear them with pride.

Comment: Suck it up, it's not a fashion parade.

Comment: I vote for wearing the cerise-pink robes.

Comment: "Cerise-pink" looks remarkably similar to Harvard's "crimson" robes, which I've worn without embarrassment.

Answer (score 9):

In the United States, there are typically two acceptable pieces of regalia to wear: either your university-specific regalia or a "generic Ph.D." regalia that is just simple black robes plus your doctoral hood.  It would seem rather gauche to me to wear non-Ph.D. regalia or to wear the regalia of a school that is not your alma mater, even if that is where your post is.  I don't know if "generic Ph.D." regalia is also accepted in the UK, where many universities have a much longer and more formal set of traditions than in the US, but I would recommend that you look into that as a possibility.

Comment: "Generic PhD regalia" should do also in the UK. I wonder what else a PhD should wear who comes from a non-anglophone country, where regalia are not customary.

Comment: @henning: I guess that boils down to the question whether "a robe, but the 'wrong' one" is still better than "no robe at all" (just formal attire, such as a suit and a tie).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I can't read your comment without thinking _The Emperor's New Robes_. :^)

Comment: @J.R., did you hear about the emperor's new paint? It's a pigment of your imagination.

Comment: My dad got his PhD at a university that wore *bright* blue robes, and lectured at a university that had red robes for a PhD. Every graduation you could pick him out of a crowd with no trouble.

Comment: I don't understand how an answer that exclusively deals with the US came to be the most upvoted answer on a question tagged [tag:united-kingdom], or why such an answer was even posted for that matter.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I totally agree with you, but it's just as bad on other Stackexchange sites. Here is another amusing example: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/should-i-leave-tips-in-latvian-hotels

Answer (score 6):

This is a matter for whichever official at your university is in charge of ceremonies; in a British university there is almost certainly someone who knows the official rules, even if the university as a whole is very relaxed about academic dress. At some universities (Oxford and Cambridge are the main examples) the rules about wearing 'local' versus 'foreign' academic dress are very strict, and still taken fairly seriously (there are only specific occasions when academic dress from other universities may be worn, and for other purposes fellows are 'incorporated' into the university so they are entitled to wear MA robes).

- If your question is 'can I get away with it', the answer is almost certainly '**yes**', assuming your institution is one of the majority that are quite relaxed about academic dress.
- If your question is 'should I wear the less gaudy robes', I would suggest the answer is '**no**'; part of your role at a graduation is to make the event as meaningful as possible for your students graduating, and wearing more impressive robes supports that.

I recommend the ['Academical Dress' Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/991333104293186/) as a source of academic dress advice and knowledge, often from the people (at the Burgon Society) who wrote the book on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can totally get away with it. The situation in the UK is much more formal than in the US, where I have seen a graduation ceremony that looked [exactly like the Comanche attack scene from *Blood Meridian*](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/328033-a-legion-of-horribles-hundreds-in-number-half-naked-or), but I have never seen anybody called out for wearing the wrong robes, except for once in Cambridge where I was gently chided for letting some ribbons hang out which were supposed to be tucked under the armpits.

Wear whatever you feel comfortable with. As long as it's academic dress, nobody will know and it doesn't really matter. (But if you did happen to get a PhD from Leeds, you are wrong about those robes! They are awesome!)

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on whether you'd get away with it, as that depends on your institution and colleagues, but wearing the wrong robes is certainly **both bad form and *rude***.

It's bad form to disrespect the rules of the ceremony, and it's rude to everyone who is graduating to do so. Moreover, it's rude to everyone who has ever got a PhD from Heriot-Watt to treat a Masters from another university as more valuable to display than your doctorate from Heriot-Watt.

You may not like it, but you neither get to choose the design of your institutes's robes not what the robes you wear *mean* and wearing the wrong gown communicates to anyone who understands that you place your masters in higher esteem to your PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Who will ever know? No one really knows what degrees you have, save the panel that hired you and the people at HR who maintain the staff records!

Spotting a degree and university by eye from a robe is a real skill that I suspect few possess. Its even rarer than bird spotting. (Never heard of robe twitchers)....

Wear what looks the best in the photos or the official video, because you will appear in many hundreds of parent photographs.

Myself, I put on the most colourful ties and waistcoats under my robe. Colour, pomp and show is what the entire ceremony is about.

Comment: _Who will ever know?_ I guess most people in your department and a few people out of it, some of whom may know what your robes look like.  (Though I doubt many would would report you to the Ministry of Robes.)

Comment: Faculty know each other's colors. We comment on them regularly at graduation, how we feel sorry for those stuck with pink for the rest of their academic lives, how much we like the deep blues, etc.

Comment: Another thing that happens is that people also borrow regalia for one reason or another.  My wife waited until she was the Dept. Chair and the school would let her charge the $800  expense before she got her own "correct" set.

Comment: I'm very confused by the suggestion that the OP's colleges wouldn't know what university the OP attended.